# NetworkManager sets nameserver to 127.0.1.1

Tags: network-manager, dns, 17.10

I upgraded to artful and suddenly have DNS problems. It looks like NetworkManager is setting a custom nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

When I change the line to 192.168.1.1, it works again. But, it gets overwritten a next network change.

Note: dnsmasq is not installed!

Comment: Did you affirmatively remove dnsmasq? It is typically installed by default in 17.10. What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo resolvconf -u` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following resolved to problem:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Now  we /etc/resolv.conf contains this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search fritz.box
```

Comment: If your problem is solved please accept your own answer so people see that your question is already solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the prevailing DNS entry is 127.0.1.1 although there is no service running for that IP. Everytime I reboot, my machine don't have DNS resolution.

Apparently, the configuration in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf is missing dns=dnsmasq which is expected because NetworkManager will setup said service at 127.0.1.1 (dnsmasq is expected to be installed).

I believe there are some crufts left from previous incarnation/installation where the DNS address is supposed to be 127.0.0.1 (this service is also running on my computer).
This should be looked into and cleaned up topside.

Comment: I have exactly this problem. Fresh install of ubuntu 17.10, wired ethernet over DHCP, all default packages, and DNS doesn't work. resolv.conf lists 127.0.1.1, but nothing is running on UDP port 53 locally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no `dns=dnsmasq` line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file and `/etc/resolv.conf` was still overwritten by Network Manager to have only `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` didn't help.

The fix was to restore a symlink for proper updating:

```
sudo ln -sf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```